# Parse() Can't Get All Element

Tags: c#, xml

i have smailler XML file i want to parse it .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GeeSuth Checker Time -->
<Geranal>
  <AftrNoon Min="20" StartAftrNoon="05:00:00" EndAftrNoon="11:01:00" />
  <Night Min="50" StartNight="2:00:00" EndNight="6:00:00" />
  <AlFajr Min="100" StartAlfajr="9:00:00" EndAlfajr="10:00:00" />
</Geranal>
```

i want to get all the value in line , like

```
<AftrNoon Min="20" StartAftrNoon="05:00:00" EndAftrNoon="11:01:00" />
```

i need save the values in string paramater :.

> Min
>
> StartAftrNoon
>
> EndAftrNoon

and save it in paramater ?

im using this :.

```
XmlReader ReaderXML = XmlReader.Create("Date.xml");
while (ReaderXML.Read())
{
    ReaderXML.IsStartElement("Geranal");
    if (ReaderXML.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && ReaderXML.Name == "AftrNoon")
    {
        //AftarNoon Fill
        txt_Min_Aftrnoon.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(0);
        dt_Aftr_start.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(1);
        dt_aftar_End.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(2);
    }
    if (ReaderXML.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && ReaderXML.Name == "Night")
    {
        txt_Min_Night.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(0);
        dt_Night_Start.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(1);
        dt_Night_end.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(2);
    }
    if (ReaderXML.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && ReaderXML.Name == "AlFajr")
    {
        txt_Min_Fajr.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(0);
        dt_Fajr_Start.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(1);
        dt_fajar_end.Text = ReaderXML.GetAttribute(2);
    }
}
```

It's Not get all elements value.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem statement.  Please review [ask] and then [edit] your question with a specific problem or error.

Comment: Use the XmlDocument class with xpath instead of XmlReader. You're making things harder on yourself by reading it serially like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your XML has a small issue with the naming of the attributes that makes it hard to parse - the element `AlFajr` has a capital `F`, yet the attributes do not. If you can fix that then this code works nicely:

```
var xd = XDocument.Load("Date.xml");

var nodes =
(
    from e in xd.Root.Elements()
    let Min = e.Attribute("Min").Value
    let Start = e.Attribute("Start" + e.Name.LocalName).Value
    let End = e.Attribute("End" + e.Name.LocalName).Value
    select new { e.Name, Min, Start, End, }
).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => new { x.Min, x.Start, x.End });
```

That gives me this:

[image: results]

Now I can use that to populate your fields very easily:

```
txt_Min_Aftrnoon.Text = nodes["AftrNoon"].Min;
dt_Aftr_start.Text = nodes["AftrNoon"].Start;
dt_aftar_End.Text = nodes["AftrNoon"].End;
txt_Min_Night.Text = nodes["Night"].Min;
dt_Night_Start.Text = nodes["Night"].Start;
dt_Night_end.Text = nodes["Night"].End;
txt_Min_Fajr.Text = nodes["AlFajr"].Min;
dt_Fajr_Start.Text = nodes["AlFajr"].Start;
dt_fajar_end.Text = nodes["AlFajr"].End;
```

---

Alternatively, you could also set up a dictionary for your text boxes and, using the above code, assign the values like this:

```
var textBoxes = new []
{
    new { Name = "AftrNoon", Min = txt_Min_Aftrnoon, Start = dt_Aftr_start, End = dt_aftar_End },
    new { Name = "Night", Min = txt_Min_Night, Start = dt_Night_Start, End = dt_Night_end },
    new { Name = "AlFajr", Min = txt_Min_Fajr, Start = dt_Fajr_Start, End = dt_fajar_end },
};

foreach (var tb in textBoxes)
{
    tb.Min.Text = nodes[tb.Name].Min;
    tb.Start.Text = nodes[tb.Name].Start;
    tb.End.Text = nodes[tb.Name].End;
}
```

---

Another alternative, that eliminates the need to fix the attribute naming issue, is to just do this:

```
var xd = XDocument.Load("Date.xml");

txt_Min_Aftrnoon.Text = xd.Root.Element("AftrNoon").Attribute("Min").Value;
dt_Aftr_start.Text = xd.Root.Element("AftrNoon").Attribute("StartAftrNoon").Value;
dt_aftar_End.Text = xd.Root.Element("AftrNoon").Attribute("EndAftrNoon").Value;
txt_Min_Night.Text = xd.Root.Element("Night").Attribute("Min").Value;
dt_Night_Start.Text = xd.Root.Element("Night").Attribute("StartNight").Value;
dt_Night_end.Text = xd.Root.Element("Night").Attribute("EndNight").Value;
txt_Min_Fajr.Text = xd.Root.Element("AlFajr").Attribute("Min").Value;
dt_Fajr_Start.Text = xd.Root.Element("AlFajr").Attribute("StartAlfajr").Value;
dt_fajar_end.Text = xd.Root.Element("AlFajr").Attribute("EndAlfajr").Value;
```

Comment: Waw . I'm so glad to see people like you here . All your coded is working successful . 
and the fainlly code is amazing . i'll use it . 
because not needed to define varable more. 
Again Thank you .

Answer (score 3):

Just put all name/value pairs to a dictionary. Using *Linq2Xml*

```
var values = XDocument.Load(filename)
            .Descendants("AftrNoon")
            .First()
            .Attributes()
            .ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value);
```

Now you can access them like

```
var min = values["Min"];
```

or

```
foreach(var kv in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + ":" + kv.Value);
}
```

Comment: You should show the output of this code given the OP's input.

Comment: @Enigmativity  `should`?  Why? Why is *posting the code how to use the results* not enough?

Comment: So that we can see that this code works. Otherwise we would need to run it ourselves and that's not terribly useful. If I had to do that on every answer in SO I would be here for ever.

Comment: @Enigmativity then don't do it. You don't have to check if you are not interested.... You are not the target of this answer... But OP should test it....

Comment: Yes, I am the target of this answer. SO's primary reason to exist is to build a library of quality questions and answers for the entire community to get value from. It is only secondary to give an answer to the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think OP can accept this little pain of testing the code if he/she want an answer..... BTW: I am not interested in  *building a library of quality questions*. (SO owners may think differently of course) But I just want to help the OP, and this is my way/

Comment: Waw! That's work , Awesome code . can you explain it to me. because i don't undrstand how this is working. But we need define more variable to saved it , Big Thank you. Regards